# iOS App is rejected with Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

Recently, I tried to update my app in AppStore. But it was rejected because of the following reasons.

But I tried in all devices with mentioned iOS version (12.2) but it is working fine.I'm unable to find solution.

So please suggest me how to fix this issue?

From Apple

```
2. 1 Performance: App Completeness
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness


We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure it will launch without crashing.

Resources

For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please review Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports.
```

Below is the CrashLog provided by Appstore review team:

> {"app_name":"AppName","timestamp":"2019-04-16 09:22:18.55
>   -0700","app_version":"1.0.16","slice_uuid":"c8914002-4b38-3da0-8e31-829f5bddbdfd","adam_id":1396367559,"build_version":"2","bundleID":"com.appname.appnameapp","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone
>   OS 12.2
>   (16E227)","incident_id":"72C0D4A0-BF23-404C-A796-F13701758240","name":"appname"}
>   Incident Identifier: 72C0D4A0-BF23-404C-A796-F13701758240
>   CrashReporter Key:   1830fca23702e57d80d0b7f4d1230373d6415b5d Hardware
>   Model:      xxx Process:             appname [33978] Path:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/540E1CAA-E3F1-4F45-85FE-AD4060B38B9A/appname.app/appname
>   Identifier:          com.appname.appnameapp Version:             2
>   (1.0.16) AppStoreTools:       10E121a Code Type:           ARM-64
>   (Native) Role:                Non UI Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>   Coalition:           com.appname.appnameapp [1885]
>
> Date/Time:           2019-04-16 09:22:18.4322 -0700 Launch Time:
>   2019-04-16 09:22:15.3728 -0700 OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.2
>   (16E227) Baseband Version:    5.55.00 Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100530ca4 Termination Signal: Trace/BPT
>   trap: 5 Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5 Terminating
>   Process: exc handler [33978] Triggered by Thread:  0

Comment: I am unable to answer you question from guideline 1. No question asked. Next steps: provide a question and possibly code to enable the question to be answered. Resources: You can go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details

Comment: how did you resolve this issue? i'm currently faced with the same and I have no errors when I run in emulators or on my own test devices.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the part of your question where you wrote:

> I tried in all devices

It seems like you might be running in the iOS Simulator instead of on a real device. The crash log says that your app was running on ARM, which means that it was probably running on a real device. Have you tried running your app on a real device? If not, off the top of my head, something that could crash your device on startup could be a missing permission string in your Info.plist if you are requesting access to something on the user's device. I have also recently read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450151/swift-ios-12-2-crash-of-the-app-on-launch) thread about a crash that a developer is experiencing on 12.2. Maybe you could look into whether or not your dependencies are in compliance with the version of Swift you are developing with.

Comment: Yeah @rpecka I tested in real devices also. I explained the same thing to Apple review team now they approved that build without any changes :)

Thanks for your response