# App crash without crash report since iOS 12.2 update

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios12

Since the upgrade to iOS 12.2 on a real device (iPhone XS Max), the app crashes after 1 second, right during the launch screen. The app was installed via TestFlight and worked fine for months.

Neither `hockeySDK` nor `Firebase Analytics` (Cashlytics) nor Apple crash reporter (Xcode > Organizer > Crashes) has reported this crash. Even the device logs do not show any crash for that app or even any crash in that time range.

After deleting and reinstalling the app from the AppStore, it works fine so far.

Unfortunately I wasn't thinking of opening the console in Xcode to maybe get some infos about the crash. Now that the app works, I cannot reproduce the crash.

App crashes since iOS 12.2 are all over social media, a common issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450151/swift-ios-12-2-crash-of-the-app-on-launch). However it seems strange that the app works after reinstalling.

What I could think of is that the app crashed for some other reason and when trying to launch it, one of the crash reporters tried to send the report and actually caused the app to crash immediately.

What could be the reason and how can I find out if any users are affected?

Comment: Does the app crash if you delete the version you installed with Xcode and reinstall the version on the App Store? Perhaps it's a compatibility issue between binaries compiled for other versions and 12.2

Comment: Good point, the app that kept crashing was installed from Xcode I believe. The reinstall was done through the App Store. An incompatibility could have caused the crash only on the Xcode installed version.

Comment: My bad, I completely misread your question and got everything backwards. If you run the app with the debugger attached, does the crash show up in Xcode?

Comment: Actually to be exact, the app that crashed was installed via TestFlight, not via Xcode debugger. That TestFlight install that always worked suddenly always crashed during launch screen since update to iOS 12.2. I cannot install the original app with debugger attached because Xcode 10.1 cannot install on iOS 12.2 and Xcode 10.2 needs external frameworks to be recompiled with Swift 5 via Carthage. So the resulting file won't be identical to the one that crashed. And the app is not available in TestFlight anymore.

Comment: There was something a long time ago that was causing my app to crash instantly because of Hockey. I think it might have been provisioning profiles or an expired or something. It might be worth checking that out.

Comment: How would I check this out?

Comment: If it was an expired profile or certificate, it would keep crashing I think, even after reinstall, because these are bound to the app.

Comment: Hi @Manuel I'm having this same issue. Would you mind telling me how you solved this?

Comment: @enigrify see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone:

I have never found out what the issue was, but as I wrote in the question, the issue self-resolved. I have not heard of any user feedback regarding this, so I assume that the issue was related to some underlying configuration change after updating iOS, *only affecting the TestFlight install.*

After 1 year I only vaguely remember that the issue was solved by something like restart or reinstall, either of the app itself or of TestFlight, or maybe making a new release available via TestFlight.